# Disable Chrome copy menu when selecting any text using touch monitor

Tags: javascript, css, html

How to disable contextmenu in chrome while on a touch screen. This pops up on selection/on long tap of any text. Is there any solution which we can manage using css or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add a listener, that catchs every touch on a section

```
document.getElementById('yoursection').addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

but note, that in that section nothing more can be touched ...

Comment: Thanks Christian for quick reply.. But on select I want to show my custom menu.. Can you please suggest is there an way to do it same..

Comment: you can just add the function that shows you menu to the anonymus function (so before or after `event.preventDefault()`)